# Collections and indexing

Tags: collections

Is there a collection type that you wouldn't want to be treated as indexable?  I'm writing a collection library and I can't think of a collection type where you wouldn't want that.  You can get and set the index, remove at an index and insert on a linked list, albeit it works differently...

Comment: Probalby not, but things like bags or certain sets? not sure

Comment: Hmm I suppose indexing a dictionary doesnt make much sense either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you allow a collection to be indexable, you take on a contract that constraints your ability to optimize the internals of your collection.

In particular, there is an implicit understanding that if you see a certain item at an index `i` at some point in time and then add more items to the collection, it would be highly unusual for the item at `i` to appear at a different index after the additions. This presents a limitation: if you wanted to implement a hash-based set with an indexer, you wouldn't be able to resize it automatically, and disregard the indexing. Your implementation will have to do more work than if you dropped the indexing requirement.